# Why when I compile cmake (with clang) in release it creates DWARF debug information?

Tags: c++, cmake, clang, clion

I have problem. Everytime when I compile in release build with cmake (using CLion), it also creates DWARF debug information, although it is release build. When I open my exe in IDA-Pro, it is really easy to reverse-engineer (even though I have no skills in reverse-engineering whatsoever). I tried setting the O3 flag, I tried using -g0, but nothing works. The debug information (DWARF) is still included in my exe, no matter what I do. The only fix I found is using llvm-strip, but I don't want to do that all the time.

When I build in Debug mode, the executable is only 4kb bigger, it has 126 kb in release, 130 in debug. And it has 46kb with llvm-strip --strip-debug. So the release build obviously contains the debug informations. Is there anyway for me to delete it with flag instead of using separate tool?

Comment: The question seems more about clang options which prevent debug info creation. CMake just calls clang with the options you have specified.

Comment: exactly, I just thought that I may give as much informations as possible. "Is there anyway for me to delete it with flag instead of using separate tool?" means clang compiler flag.